# MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Product Key

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

We are needing to perform a repair installation of our MS SQL Server 2008 R2 installation and cannot locate our original product key.  Is there some way in which we can recover our product key from the existing machine's registry before we uninstall and re-install the software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you purchased Sql Server, there may not be a separate product key:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlsetupandupgrade/thread/690741ca-2587-4e35-95b1-8caf8ff76e06

> When you get SQL Server via the Volume Licensing Service Center, usually the product key is populated automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try over the top solutions [product key finder](http://www.ottsolutions.com/products.htm). I have had to use this tool several times. Or you could look around the registry at this location: **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Setup** under **ProductCode**

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  That key in the registry seems to be in some type of encoded format.  Do you know how one can go about decoding that value into the key that we normally find on the box, etc.

Comment: Ah, right, its hashed. You can use magicaljellybean key finder program or the over the top solution to un-hash the code.

Comment: Unless an idiot writes a pseudo has, a hash is not reversible. Per definition. Like your passport number can not be decrunched to your real name.

Comment: Try this to reverse it ... http://mspowershell.blogspot.com/2009/02/retrieveing-windows-product-key.html

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully used [Belarc Advisor free version](http://www.belarc.com/free_download.html) to extract serial numbers for all the Microsoft product lines.  Added bonus of having an inventory of your machine is handy to have around.